# use IF() with TIMEVALUE() in excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, time

I have the folowing formula:

`=IF(TIMEVALUE("14:30") - TIMEVALUE(NOW()) < TIMEVALUE("00:00"),"Past","Future")`

Excel is giving me ERROR, i checked all formulas individually and they all give me the time value (which in theory should be enough to compare with an IF statement).

How come that i keep on getting error. Some cell formats not correct or something? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Don't put 'NOW()' inside a 'TIMEVALUE' function.

Comment: Why not? I need the current time? What do you propose?

Comment: Just use NOW() without the TIMEVALUE. TIMEVALUE expects text and turns it into a time, as with your other uses. But NOW is already a time, so the function fails.

Comment: Function still fails when i put only NOW().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to **evaluate the formula step by step** to see, if this is what you want.

**Working formula:**
`=IF(TIMEVALUE("14:30") - NOW() < TIMEVALUE("00:00");"Past";"Future")`

**Evaluated arguments, using [F9 key]:**
`=IF(0,604166666666667 - 42719,6943635416 < 0;"Past";"Future")`

You will always get the `"Past"` as returned value.

### Explanation of date and time in Excel

The TIME in Excel is a **proportion of a day**. `"00:00" = 0.00` and `"24:00" = 1.00`. Other values of TIME are DECIMALS between 0 and 1.

The DATE is a number of days since the first day. `"1900-01-01" = 1` and `"2000-01-01" = 36526`. It is always an INTEGER.

Combining DATA and TIME (like in `NOW()` function) gives you an INTEGER + DECIMAL. When I evaluated the `NOW()` it returned `42719,6943635416`

The `TIMEVALUE` function expects a STRING/TEXT that is considered a TIME and converts that STRING/TEXT to DECIMAL between <0; 1>.

### Links

[MS - How to use dates and times in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214094)
[Trump-Excel:Identify Errors Using Excel Formula Debugging (2 Methods)](https://trumpexcel.com/excel-formula-debugging/)

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! Your function seems to work. Now i can tweak it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Convert the `Now` to string first, using `Text` function, then it will work as expected.

`TEXT(NOW(),"HH:MM:SS")`

Final formula:

`=IF((TIMEVALUE("11:30") - TIMEVALUE(TEXT(NOW(),"HH:MM:SS"))) < TIMEVALUE("00:00"),"Past","Future")`

Comment: `Now` returns the value comprising of `Date` and `Time` both. So if you compare just a timevalue against Now, its always going to be past.

Comment: #ERROR is what i get

Comment: strange, as far as I know, there is no #ERROR type in Excel.

Comment: To avoid the need to make it a text value then convert back to number just use MOD() to strip the integer part: `=IF((TIMEVALUE("11:30") - MOD(NOW(),1)) < TIMEVALUE("00:00"),"Past","Future")`

Comment: @ScottCraner, once again on the dot.