# the same date time group stored with different doubles

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to compare date time groups (DTGs). As you can see below the same DTG are stored as slightly different doubles.

13/11/2016 13:22:22 = 42687.5571990**741000000**
13/11/2016 13:22:22 = 42687.5571990**162000000**

Comparing them in VBA impossible. ie if A=B Then .... doesn't work.
Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: Try `CDate()` the values, so it converts to date before comparing.

Comment: How precise you want your comparison to be? Days? Seconds? Miliseconds? Exact? The decimal part of the number is a fraction of a 24hour day. Ex. `42687.5` is 13/11/2016 12:00:00

Comment: Didn't work but thanks for the tip. Didn't know CDate was a thing. I think I need to round my values to the nearest second as they are defined to ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation of the mismatch

The Date and Time is stored as a Integer Number (Day) and a Decimal part (Time). The time is a proportion of a day. So 6 hours is a 1/4 of a day = 0,25 in Decimal. See more in [answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41168018/4636801).

### MRound to the nearest second

To round the Date Time to nearest second you can use the [`MROUND function`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MROUND-function-c299c3b0-15a5-426d-aa4b-d2d5b3baf427).

> Returns a number rounded to the desired multiple.
>   Syntax: MROUND(number, multiple).

In the picture below, you can see Double values for your Date and Times + some other examples. Next is the same, just formatted as a Date and Time with miliseconds. Next is the Mround to seconds conversion.

For D4 the formula is : `=MROUND(B4;1/$B$1)`

Note: You may need to play with `,` and `.`, because of your language settings.

[image]

You can use this knowledge and function in your VBA code.